# Is there a way of getting the inset axes by "asking" the axes it is embedded in?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have several subplots, `axs`, some of them with embedded inset axes. I would like to get the data plotted in the insets by iterating over the main axes. Let's consider this minimal reproducible example:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3)
x = np.array([0,1,2])
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    if i != 1:
        ins = ax.inset_axes([.5,.5,.4,.4])
        ins.plot(x, i*x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way of doing something like

```
data = []
for ax in axs:
    if ax.has_inset():       # "asking" if ax has embedded inset
        ins = ax.get_inset() # getting the inset from ax
        line = ins.get_lines()[0]
        dat = line.get_xydata()
        data.append(dat)
print(data)
# [array([[0., 0.],
#         [1., 0.],
#         [2., 0.]]),
#  array([[0., 0.],
#         [1., 2.],
#         [2., 4.]])]
```

Comment: The question lacks a complete [mre]. Additionally, an `axes` should only have an inset axes with the use of [`ax.inset_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html). As shown in the documentation, the the use of `.inset_axes` should be assigned to a new object (e.g. `axin1 = ax.inset_axes(...)`), which can be used for plotting and other methods. Additionally, **Warning: This method is experimental as of 3.0, and the API may change.**

Comment: The scope of the question indicates an inefficient plot implementation. There should be no reason to plot some data onto the inset axes and then need a secondary method to get the data from the axes.

Comment: @Trenton it's always possible that the figures were generated by a library and OP want to change something without having to patch the library. I agree that a MRE would be useful.

Comment: @mozway You're correct, that is a valid case, though no other libraries were indicated. Since this function is experimental, I probably wouldn't consider using it in a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`get_children`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html) and a filter to retrieve the insets:

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes

def get_insets(ax):
    return [c for c in ax.get_children()
            if isinstance(c, Axes)]

for ax in fig.axes:
    print(get_insets(ax))
```

Output:

```
[<Axes:label='inset_axes'>]
[]
[<Axes:label='inset_axes'>]
```

For your particular example:

```
data = []
for ax in fig.axes:
    for ins in get_insets(ax):
        line = ins.get_lines()[0]
        dat = line.get_xydata()
        data.append(dat)
```

Output:

```
[array([[0., 0.],
        [1., 0.],
        [2., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0.],
        [1., 2.],
        [2., 4.]])]
```